# Unbiasedness for inverse estimator of negative binomial distribution

Tags: expected-value, maximum-likelihood

> Let $X$ be negatively binomially distributed to parameters $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p \in] 0,1[$, i.e.
> $$
> \mathbb{P}(X=k)=\binom{n+k-1}{k} p^n(1-p)^k, \quad k \in \mathbb{N}_0.
> $$
> Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ be known and $p \in\, ]0,1[$ be unknown.
> The maximum likelihood estimator for $p$ is given by
> $$
> \widehat{p}(k)=\frac{n}{k+n}.
> $$

How can you show that

> $1 / \widehat{p}$ is *unbiased* for $\frac{1}{p}$, where $\widehat{p}$ denotes the maximum likelihood estimator from part (a).

The inverse of the estimator is unbiased for $1/p$. Let us note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{n+\overline{X}}{n}\right]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{n+\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[1+\frac{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i}{n}\right]=1+\frac{1}{n^2}\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right]\\
&=1+\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[X_i\right]=1+\frac{1}{n^2}n\mathbb{E}\left[X_1\right]=1+\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{E}\left[X_1\right]...
\end{aligned}
$$
thanks for the help the rest is clear.

Comment: $E[X_1] = n(1-p)/p$  (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)
You made a mistake : It is $1 + \frac{1}{n}E[X_1]$ and you get $1 + (1-p)/p = 1/p$